# "Find the unique x in the interval [0,pi] with..."

Tags: calculus

I don't understand what I should calculate if is said: "find the unique x", e.g. in the following exercise:

"Find the unique x in the interval [0,pi] with cos(x) = 0,5 * sqrt(3)"

Comment: This means there is one and only one value of $x$ between $0$ and $\pi$ for which $\cos (x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and you should find that value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking to find the $x$ value in $[0,\pi]$ which satisfies $\cos x = \sqrt3/2$. Basically, you're told there is some number $x$ between $0$ and $\pi$ and the cosine of that number is $\sqrt3 /2$ and the question is to determine what this $x$ is. Since there is one (which the question sort of allows you to assume) they use the word "unique". But a look at the unit circle reveals that this unique $x=\pi/6$.

Answer (score 0):

"find the unique $x$" means

**1,** Such $x$ must exist;

**2,** it is the only one.